# android horizontal image slider

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery

i'm trying to create an `image` `slider`, showing only one `image` per slide. 
This is working good on <= 5'' screens but when I go > 5'' the all the images appears side by side, showing more then one image per slide. This is the layout I'm using:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/custodiastampante" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/custodiastampante" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

How can I show always only 1 image per slide? (Even if using another tecnique like `ViewPager` or `gallery`?

Comment: place only one ImageView into your interior linearlayout

Comment: @Martin you suggest to use one `linearLayout` for each `imageview` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the height and width of the imageViews programmatically. I would suggest you to find the dimensions of the screen , and then set the width of the imageviews accordingly.

This is the code for finding dimensions:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

And here is how you can set the size of the imageView:

```
imageView.setWidth(width);
```

Comment: one image per slide - you're talking about an adapter. YOu can either do as you are - place all kinds of imageviews inside your linearlayout, or create an adapter/viewpager that will let you show one image for each swipe.